# DJANGO Rest API - Method POST Not Allowed

Tags: python, django, api

This is my views.py file. I tried POST on Postman but no luck. I can however, easily add through the API view that Django comes with. What am I missing? I have commented out the permissions for now. I basically copied this from the Django Rest Framework Tutorial but it provides no details about how to send a POST request.

```
class SnippetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    This viewset automatically provides `list`, `create`, `retrieve`,
    `update` and `destroy` actions.
    Additionally we also provide an extra `highlight` action.
    """
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer
    # permission_classes = (
    #     permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
    #     IsOwnerOrReadOnly, )

    @action(detail=True, renderer_classes=[renderers.StaticHTMLRenderer])
    def highlight(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        snippet = self.get_object()
        return Response(snippet.highlighted)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """
    This viewset automatically provides `list` and `detail` actions.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Here is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('snippets.urls')),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^schema/$', schema_view),
    url(r'^docs/', include_docs_urls(title=API_TITLE, description=API_DESCRIPTION))
]
```

and this is the app level urls.py

```
# Create a router and register our viewsets with it.
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'snippets', views.SnippetViewSet)
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)

# The API URLs are now determined automatically by the router.
# Additionally, we include the login URLs for the browsable API.
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls))
]
```

Comment: Add your urls.py and show which URL/end-point you have used to sent the request?

Comment: If you try to post with postman you will get 403 forbidden that because you need to include csrf token

Comment: inside your class, define a `post` method. I had a similar problem and that solved that

Answer (score 0):

Best is to add a reference to a document in another collection such as

```
Ref(Collection("collectionName", targetDocumentID))
```

I am still researching if an actual document can exist there instead of a document reference.